# Bar chart does not appear with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm a beginner trying out Chart.js and I'm having trouble with getting my bar chart to appear. When I try and run this code all I get is a blank screen, any idea why?

```
<div id="chart">
<canvas id="myGraph" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
var myData = {
        labels: ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003"],
        datasets: [{
        label: 'Test chart',
        data: [20, 50, 10, 12],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
   },
});

var ctx = document.getElementById("myGraph").getContext("2d");
var debt = new Chart(ctx).Bar(myData);

</script>
```

Comment: remove  ',
});' at the end, before 'var ctx'

Comment: @natchkebiailia Hi I tried it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several typos in your JSON literal.
I rewrote it like so (see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lvx4gLn/12/) for the JSFiddle)

```
var config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
        labels: ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003"],
        datasets: [{
        label: 'Test chart',
        data: [20, 50, 10, 12],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
  }
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("myGraph");
var debt = new Chart(ctx, config);
```